# git: How to change the commit message of an already made commit non-interactively without changing the commit ID?

Tags: git

Is there a **command/script** which takes the `commit ID` or `filename` of an already made commit as input, and changes the commit message without changing the `commit ID`?

I looked into options like `git filter-branch`, `git rebase`, `git notes` but they dont allow change for single commits and they are all interactive. Is there a way to do it non-interactively?

Comment: You can do this for the last commit easily with `git commit --amend -C (message)`. For a higher up commit, it's a bit trickier. You will need to rebase or filter-branch as you said, but I don't know how to make this automatable. I'm keen to see some answers too :)

Comment: No, `--amend` will change the commit ID.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot change a commit message without changing the commit id because the commit message is part of the data that is hashed to form the commit id.

This is why all the tools which change a single commit generally change all the subsequent commits (`filter-branch`, `rebase`, etc.) because once you change one commit in a history all the descendants must change because they have a new ancestor with a new id.

Comment: OK, thank :).. I totally agree to your point.. Is there still a way to change the commit message of a particular commit ID? I am looking for a script/command that might help..