# abusing git to edit an incorrect commit message without rebasing or filtering

Tags: git, commit, rebase

I'm asking a question that is the **intentionally incorrect** version of [How to modify existing, unpushed commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/edit-an-incorrect-commit-message-in-git) , and I've read the canon response on commit ids depending on the commit message content in [git: How to change the commit message of an already made commit non-interactively without changing the commit ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251852/git-how-to-change-the-commit-message-of-an-already-made-commit-non-interactivel) .

Only for those that might say "no, you're going to do it the correct way": Those replies are "the only good way" and I'm aware of it. Only, I'm in the position that doing things the correct way is not really useful to me because the cost would be too high right now; I think I'm aware of the mess that might happen and I'm prepared to pay the price of inconsistent git repo replicas later on. I'm also aware that this is not the "proper" approach from a project management standpoint, the thing is that I have to keep current project time into consideration too. "correct" now can lead to failure.

**The Problem:**
A sensitive information ended up in a commit message that has been pushed for ages and the repo was subsequently heavily cloned and branched. We'll correct the main repo and clones later on (e.g. rebasing the commit and then rebasing the subsequent developments as soon as we have time), but I have to strip the information from the Origin - right now.

I'd like to either:
- change or delete the commit message content without changing the id; should not matter if leads to inconsistency since that commit is very old and is very, very unlikely to be rebased/cherrypicked/filter-branched.
or
- or **nuke the commit**, reconnecting its parent as the parent of the child commit, without rewriting the id of the latter (same inconsistency problem, yeah).

or something along those lines.

I've stumbled on the **git-replace** manual entry but it's not entirely clear to me if it requires the original commit (content) to persist, or if it can be "nuked" (or hidden to subsequent clone operations).

thank you in advance ;)

ps: you might wander why I didn't continue to post in the original threads; that's because what I'm asking is definitely "non-canon" and I don't want to "deceive" users that are not in my peculiar situation into doing very dangerous things.

and yes, we'll keep multiple backups of the original repo just in case.

Comment: twalberg comment is a write-only contribution that actually states something true without answering the question, and frankly it feels like he didn't try to read the question (where did I say that I wanted to end with a consistent git database? quite the contrary, since I was confident it was impossible for the exact same reason you are mentioning). Thanks to Makoto and especially Aasmund for their replies (both correct, and_useful_).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting - I wasn't aware of `git replace`. The following *might* work, but I'm not sure if there might exist some command that will get thrown off by it. Let's say that the bad commit's hash is `66ba4c10a3d85f33c1123b5107d5857d646c13eb`.

```
git checkout 66ba4c10a3d85f33c1123b5107d5857d646c13eb
git commit --amend -m "Safe message."
git replace 66ba4c10a3d85f33c1123b5107d5857d646c13eb `rev-parse HEAD`
rm .git/objects/66/ba4c10a3d85f33c1123b5107d5857d646c13eb
```

The first three commands create the cleaned commit and make the replacement. The last command physically deletes the original commit object (note the slash after the first two characters of the hash). I ran `git fsck` after this, and it didn't complain, so it looks like it is safe.

However, this only works if the commit hasn't been included in a *packfile* yet, which your commit most likely has been. You should look into `git prune` and `git repack`. Also, I'm not sure if this replacement will be propagated by `git push` or `git pull`. Even if it is, the deletion won't, so the `rm`/`prune`/`repack` needs to be repeated (*after* the replacement) in all other repos. Still not sure about how to confirm that the commit object is completely gone.

Comment: to both confirm and contribute a fragment of information: actually i did try something along those lines on a toy repository with commits not already packed; it turns out that it seems to work, but if you later trigger a rebase that cross the replaced commit, rebase fails.

Comment: @Primate: Sounds reasonable - in other words, you're left with a repository that's "mostly", but not completely, functional. Also, what happens if you try to clone the repository?

Answer (score 1):

Simply put: no, this isn't possible.  You're going to be rewriting history, and when you rewrite history, you generate a new SHA.  Subsequently, all commits that referred to the now replaced commit or commits will dangle.

There are tools out there that make this sort of operation less painful, such as [BFG Repo Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/), but ultimately that still involves:

- Accessing to the commit that contained the file with the sensitive info
- Editing the file
- Committing the changes
- Forcing the changes to propagate through *all of its children*

You won't lose any of your data in doing this, per se; you'd just get rid of the poisoned commit.

The reason you can't simply replace the contents of a commit is due to the way a [SHA is computed for a commit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8873169/1079354) - it doesn't just include things like the contents of the files, but also the time and date when it was created.

Lastly, stripping the info is still going to be a time-intensive operation, as you have to coordinate the removal of the information from everyone else's box.  In any event, **consider that secret compromised** and alter any system that makes use of it.