# git: edit a local commit without changing its commit id

Tags: git-commit

Is there a way to edit/add files to an existing commit with out changing its commit ID.

I used git commit --amend but it changes the commit ID.

This is required for the reviewboard, as it generates reviews based on commit ids.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git: How to change the commit message of an already made commit non-interactively without changing the commit ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251852/git-how-to-change-the-commit-message-of-an-already-made-commit-non-interactivel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just impossible. If you have to edit/add files, it means the patch does not pass the code review. Just make another commit, or --amend to update the original commit, and make another review.

Comment: Understood. I'm able to update the same review with new commit id.